# Uber Deep link with promocode webhook

Tags: uber-api

Case:

1. I bought Uber Event with promocodes.
2. Made a deep link from my app to Uber:

   https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=xxxyyy-zzz&action=applyPromo&promo=existingtestpromo
3. Set up an API webhook in the Uber Dashboard to receive POST at https://45.55.254.130/uber/webhook/ (no domain yet and self-signed SSL)
4. User followed the link and made a ride. He finished the ride ok.
5. No webhook received at all(django+uwsgi logs empty on that url). I also tested that url manually sending POST request from code - it works.

**Are the webhooks used at all when using deep links with promocodes?**

Answer (score 2):

Webhooks do not get sent when you use the deeplinks (promo code or set pickup). You can receive webhooks when you make a ride request using `POST v1/requests` or when you have the `all_trips` scope.

Here's information about making a ride request using the API: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sdks/introduction

And here's information about `all_trips` scope (the feature is called Trip Experiences): https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorial-trip-experiences-getting-started

Comment: How can i add the promocode to the rides made via API? Uber doesn't have information about promocodes except of deep links in Docs.

Comment: And how do i know if my promocode was used? (i want to check it in the code)

Comment: We are thinking about better ways to handle promo code usage. Today it is not possible to manage promo codes with the API.